# How to run the query of a FilterQueryProvider asynchronously?

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous, android-listview

I'm using a FilterQueryProvider to filter the content of a list view which is backed up by a custom CursorAdapter.

To use the FilterQueryProvider you have to override the runQuery() method which returns a Cursor object. Now I'm wondering how to query for the cursor asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Is there some kind of best practice? I couldn't find any information whether the the runQuery() method is executed on the UI-thread or on its own thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation :

> Filtering operations performed by calling filter(CharSequence,
>   android.widget.Filter.FilterListener) are performed asynchronously

So your code should look like this :

```
private void filterList(CharSequence constraint) {
    final YourListCursorAdapter adapter = 
        (YourListCursorAdapter) getListAdapter();
    final Cursor oldCursor = adapter.getCursor();
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(filterQueryProvider);
    adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint, new FilterListener() {
        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
            // assuming your activity manages the Cursor 
            stopManagingCursor(oldCursor);
            final Cursor newCursor = adapter.getCursor();
            startManagingCursor(newCursor);
            // safely close the oldCursor
            if (oldCursor != null && !oldCursor.isClosed()) {
                oldCursor.close();
            }
        }
    });
}

private FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        return dbHelper.getListCursor(constraint);
    }
};
```

<sub>Sources : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057364/filterqueryprovider-filter-and-listview) and [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java)</sub>

Comment: What is ````dbHelper````?

Answer (score 0):

According to [CursorAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#runQueryOnBackgroundThread%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) you can use `CursorAdapter#runQueryOnBackgroundThread`