# Filter two strings in the same ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have an sqLite database that contains a table that has 3 columns, I'm using in my layout an edittext and a `ListView`. What I've done by now is applying a search using the edittext and displaying the filtered results in the `ListView`.

The following code is applied to the edittext called `myFilter`, words is the implecursoradapter :

```
myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        words.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }
});
```

What I want to do is to filter two Charsequences, for example I want to display in my listView words that starts with a and b, can I do something like that (for example `words.getFilter().filter("a","b");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `FilterQueryProvider` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698945/2020889). The `constraint` parameter should represent your search query (i.e. pack "a" and "b" into a single `CharSequence`. It may be a json, comma-separated String or part of an SQL query). Then filter your values inside `runQuery(CharSequence constraint)`, for example, like this:

```
// Constraint is "a,b"
private FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        String[] queryParameters = constraint.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < queryParameters.length(); i++) {
            queryParameters[i] += "%";
        }
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"column_name"}, 
            "column_name LIKE '?' OR column_name LIKE '?'", queryParameters , null, null, null);
    }
};
```

Then the filtering is done by a single call

```
words.getFilter().filter("a,b");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to query data base if you already have values that you want to search from, To accomplish that you can extend your simpleCursorAdapter where you will implement your own filtering and handle publishing results.