# filtering with loadermanager and content provider

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

My fragment implements the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks<Cursor>` interface to load a list view from a content provider using a custom cursor adaptor. I use a SearchView widget to filter the data in the list view by restarting the loader as suggested by the doc http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting.

I have two questions with this approach :

1. When I use `restartLoader()`, only the `onCreateLoader()` and then `onLoadFinished()` are called. I do not see a call to `onLoaderReset()` in the logcat. That means `myadaptor.swapCursor(null)` is never done during the search. So does the old cursor get leaked? Do i need to do `myadaptor.swapCursor(null)` before every call to `restartLoader()` ?
2. Is there a more efficient approach to filter data? Because it seems way too expensive to restart the entire loader for every character entered by the user. The Android source of `restartLoader()` at http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java#648 does a lot of work of tearing down the loader resources and recreating it. It would have been more efficient if i could just do a simple requery of the data.

**Code :**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        Bundle queryBundle = new Bundle();
        queryBundle.putString("SearchQuery", query);
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, queryBundle, myFragment.this);
        return true;
    }
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle queryBundle) {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    if(queryBundle != null){
        selection = myTable.COLUMN_ABC + " like ?";
        selectionArgs = new String[] {"%" + queryBundle.getString("SearchQuery") + "%"};
    }
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    myadaptor.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    myadaptor.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: when you call restrartLoder is onLoadFinisched called?

Comment: also did you try to use FilterQueryProvider?

Comment: @pskink yes, as mentioned in #1, `onLoadFinished` is called. `FilterQueryProvider` looks interesting. The examples i found does not involve loaders, example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5057824/2105986. Do you have a sample code?

Comment: if onLoadFinished() is called so whats the problem? if using FQP just return a Cursor you get from ContentResolver. query

Comment: sample code,  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara

Comment: @pskink i am just looking for a more efficient way than using `restartLoader()` to filter data on every character change. I am not sure how beneficial using FQP with a loader is. Since the loader manages the cursor, the loader will anyway have to be restarted. So i don't see any advantage of using FQP. Thanks for the link but that does not involve loaders either.

Comment: with FQP you dont use loaders,  just return a Cursor in runQuery, you have your own ContentProvider so call ContentResolver.query method